# Check to see if all words in an ArrayList are in a string array and in order?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to iterate through an ArrayList and make sure that each element of the ArrayList shows up in order in a String array.

This my code so far:

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int keywordLocationInPhrase = -1;
    int nextKeywordLocationInPhrase = -1;

    do {
        if (keywords.get(x).equals(phrase[y])) {
            keywordLocationInPhrase = y;
        } else {
            y++;
            continue;
        }
        x++;

    } while (keywordLocationInPhrase == -1);
```

I get stuck here because I don't know how to get the nextKeyWordLocationInPhrase's position.

All help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Example:

If the keywords list is:

```
[dog, cat]
```

And the array of Strings to match is:

```
[cat, toy, rat, dog]
```

This would be incorrect as even though the keywords are in the array of Strings, they do not show up in order.

It would be valid in the following case:

If the keywords list is:

```
[dog, cat]
```

And the array of Strings to match is:

```
[dog, toy, rat, cat]
```

Comment: Give an example with a good input and a bad input

Comment: Added an example. Let me know if you need a better description!

Comment: Please check my answer bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following maybe an easier solution:

```
int keyWordIndex = 0; //moves only when needed
boolean allMatch = true;
for(String word : phrase){
   if(keywords.contains(word)){
      allMatch &= (word.equals(keyword.get(keyWordIndex++));
   }
}

//if allMatch is true at this point the order is respected.
```

Comment: with this solution, if there are absolutely no keywords in the phrase(keywords.contains(word) is always false), then allMatch will equal true even though there are no matches.

Comment: @Justin empty set is a subset of every set.

Comment: if keywords are `[dog, cat]` and phrase is `[mouse, squirrel]` your solution will return true even though there are no matches.

Comment: You didn't get my comment. If there are no words then you can assume they are in order, because, no words is a subset of keywords.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need all the keywords in the phrase.  That's how his examples are and his instructions are that EACH element of the ArrayList shows up in order in a String array.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is loop through all phrase and check for keyword;

```
 int y = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < phrase.lenght; i++){
       if((y < keyword.size()) && phrase[i].equals(keyword.get(y)){
         y++;
       }
 }
 return y==keyword.size();
```

This returns true in your valid cases and false in invalid cases.

Comment: Does this make they are in order?

Comment: yes, if it doesn't match the first keyword, it never checks for the others

Comment: What is there are 2 and 3 are swapped?

Comment: it tries to match keywords in order.  after it matches 1, it only tries to match 2.  after it matches 2, it only tries to match 3, and so on

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep your coding style and thinking instead of you then I refactored your codes:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();

        keywords.add("cat");
        keywords.add("dog");
        String[] phrase = {"cat", "toy", "rat", "dog"};


        do {
        if(x == keywords.size()) {
            System.out.println("success");
            return;
        }


        if(y == phrase.length - 1 && (x < keywords.size() - 1 || !keywords.get(x).equals(phrase[y]))) {
            System.out.println("failed");
            return;
        }

        if (keywords.get(x).equals(phrase[y])) {
            x++;
        } else {
            y++;
        }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my crack at the solution. I use maps for better performance when scanning the words array. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("dog");
    values.add("cat");
    values.add("sam");
    String[] words = new String[5];
    words[0] = "dog";
    words[1] = "toy";
    words[2] = "rat";
    words[3] = "cat";
    words[4] = "sam";
    System.out.println(wordsMatch(values, words));
}

public static boolean wordsMatch(List<String> keywords, String[] words) {
    int[] foundIndexes = new int[words.length];
    int foundIdx = 0;
    //convert our words array to a map for a faster lookup and we have the index
    Map<String, Integer> wrdMap = getIndexMapFromWords(words);
    // we have more values then words we know all our values is not in the list of words
    // so return false
    if (keywords.size() > words.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (String kw : keywords) {
        Integer idx = wrdMap.get(kw);
        if (idx == null) { // we don't have the word, false
            return false;
        }

        if (foundIdx == 0) {
            foundIndexes[foundIdx++] = idx;
        } else {
            int prevIdx = foundIndexes[foundIdx - 1];
            if (prevIdx > idx) { // not in order false
                return false;
            } else { // add new idx
                foundIndexes[foundIdx++] = idx;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static Map<String, Integer> getIndexMapFromWords(String[] convertWords) {
    Map<String, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
    int idx = 0;
    for (String wrd : convertWords) {
        indexMap.put(wrd, idx++);
    }
    return indexMap;
}
```